# show some view from laravel method

Tags: laravel

I want to show my content in view but it doesn't show anything

```
public function myMethod(Request $request)
{
    $this->showQuestion()
}





public function showQuestion($tester, $testerAnswers, $user)
    {
        $testerAnswerNum = $testerAnswers->count();

        $questionIdsAnswered = $testerAnswers->pluck('question_id');
        $question = UserAnswer::where("user_id", $tester->user_id)->whereNotIn('question_id', $questionIdsAnswered)->orderBy("created_at", "desc")->first();


        $question->question->items;

        $questionNum = UserAnswer::where("user_id", $tester->user_id)->count();
        $userName = $user->name;


        return view('create_answer.answer_a_question', compact('question', 'testerAnswerNum', 'questionNum', 'userName'));
    }
```

and my view file (create_answer.answer_a_question.blade.php):

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>پاسخ به سوالات</title>

    <style>
        .item:hover{
            background: #8BC34A;
        }


        .item{
            background: #eeeeee;
            float: right;
            width: 40%;
            margin: 10px;
            max-width: 200px;
        }
        button {
            background-color: Transparent;
            background-repeat:no-repeat;
            border: none;
            cursor:pointer;
            overflow: hidden;
            outline:none;
        }
        p{
            text-align: center;
            margin: 10px;
        }
        img{
            max-width: 150px;
            max-height: 150px;
            display: block;
            margin-left: 0.1px;

        }

        button.selected{
            background:red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>




<p>{{$testerAnswerNum+1}}/$questionNum}}</p>

<p>{{$userName." ".$question->tester_question_text}}</p>





@for($i=0;$i<sizeof($question->items);$i++)
    @php

        $item=$question->items[$i];

    @endphp
    <div class="item border border-secondary rounded" onclick="redirect('{{$item->id}}')" >
        <img  class="img-fluid" src="{{{$item->image}}}" alt="">
        <p class="d">{{$item->item_text}}</p>
    </div>

@endfor
<hr >
<br>
<br>
<button onclick="reload()"  style="background: #ffff;color: #3f9ae5;size: 10px;text-align: center">یک سوال دیگر</button>

<form  id="form" action="{{route('store_question')}}" method="post">
    @csrf
    <input  type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{$user->id}}">
    <input  type="hidden" name="question_id" value="{{$question->id}}">
    <input  type="hidden" id="item_id" name="item_id"  >

</form>


</body>
</html>
```

and my UserAnswer file :

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class UserAnswer extends Model
{


    public function question()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(question::class);
    }

}
```

my question model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class question extends Model
{


    public function items()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Item::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would check the file structure... Check the extension of your view file (that should be .blade.php) that has to be in resources/views/create_answer

Comment: View should be like `resources/views/create_answer/answer_a_question.blade.php`

Comment: @num8er I fixed it but it's not working still

Comment: enable debug mode in `.env` file and check if there are any error

Comment: please add `UserAnswer` file to Your question. I think You're trying to get related record but it crashes.

Comment: also You're getting single question how item field can be an array? please add `Question` model too

Comment: @ceejayoz and another user both removed material in this question that was added to defeat the question quality filter, and it was restored twice. Please don't do this - readability is important here. Thanks!

Comment: (The question quality filter is not perfect, but if you find you cannot post a question, add some more description text - there is always more material you can add.)

Comment: Is there an Error or does not just display content?

Comment: @FaridVatani   anything not shows!

Comment: @halfer better way was delete your answer against of restoring my question and confuse others anyway thanks

Comment: I suspect your change might invalidate the answer that was first given, and if it does, it will need to be rolled back to the earlier state. Given a choice between the first state of the question and what you believe is the real question, we always go for the first question. It is not fair on num8er if the question is modified to the degree their answer no longer makes sense. I wonder if this just needs to be put on hold now.

Comment: Do not edit the question to [invalidate existing answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290704/3956566).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the problem! You are calling the function but not returning anything.

In above issue the `showQuestion()` method return view for `myMethod()` and `myMethod()` don't use it, it will be work with add return in  `myMethod()` like this:

```
public function myMethod(Request $request)
{
    $this->showQuestion()
}
```

should change to:

```
public function myMethod(Request $request)
{
     return $this->showQuestion();
}
```

Comment: This could do with some indentation and, critically, semi-colons and dollar-symbols.

Answer (score 3):

You were trying to "hop" over `question` relation to get `items`.

So just pick `question_id` of one "unanswered answer" and then get question using `with('items')`.

Also it's unclear how You get `$tester, $testerAnswers, $user`.

So below are ideas how to fix Your issues:

Action:

```
public function showQuestion($tester, $testerAnswers, $user)
{
    $testerAnswerNum = $testerAnswers->count();

    $questionIdsAnswered = $testerAnswers->pluck('question_id');
    $unansweredOne = UserAnswer::where("user_id", $tester->user_id)
                               ->whereNotIn('question_id', $questionIdsAnswered)
                               ->orderBy("created_at", "desc")
                               ->first(['question_id']);

    $question = question::with('items')->find($unansweredOne->question_id);

    $questionNum = UserAnswer::where("user_id", $tester->user_id)->count();
    $userName = $user->name;


    return view('answers.answer_a_question', compact('question', 'testerAnswerNum', 'questionNum', 'userName'));
}

public function myMethod(Request $request) 
{ 
    /* 
      here You get:
        $tester
        $testerAnswers
        $user
      to pass them as arguments of
      method on next line
    */
    return $this->showQuestion($tester, $testerAnswers, $user);
}
```

View:

```
@foreach($question->items AS $item)

    <div class="item border border-secondary rounded" onclick="redirect('{{$item->id}}')" >
        <img  class="img-fluid" src="{{{$item->image}}}" alt="">
        <p class="d">{{$item->item_text}}</p>
    </div>

@endforeach
```

also change filename 
from: `create_answer.answer_a_question.blade.php`
to: `answer_a_question.blade.php` 
and put it inside of folder: `resources/views/answers/` (create it if not exists)
keep in mind for laravel `view` helper `.` (dot) means `/` (directory separator).

Comment: can you tell me what was the problem, please?

Comment: @AliGhafari it's just a guess, read my updated answer

Comment: thanks for helping I solved the problem, you can see  my own answer